# How can I know if I leave the screen already with tab navigation (react-navigation)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I am using react navigation (tab navigation) for my app. But how can I know if I leave the screen already?

For example, I have Screen A and Screen B. And I have a timer in my screen A but when I click Screen B, I want the timer stop. Before I use react navigation, I can simply use componentWillunmount function. However, I think when I use tab navigation, the first screen (Screen A) hasn't been destroy or unmount when I go to the screen B.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at [`this`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44034430/react-navigation-and-component-lifecycle) answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Tab Navigator you can use [special events](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-prop.html#addlistener-subscribe-to-updates-to-navigation-lifecycle) to define current active screen and events like "focus" and "blur"